# How to mask some cells of a heatmap plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, visualization, heatmap

I plotted the following heatmap:
[image]

using this code:

```
data = {'Month':['August','August','August','August','August','August','August','August','August','August','August','August',
 'February','February','February','February','February','February','February','February','February','February','February','February'],
'Day':['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday',
 'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday',],
'Temperature':[34,32,33,36,37,35,29,32,33,32,36,30,
 19,22,21,17,15,14,19,20,22,20,19,18],
'WorkingHours':[0,9.5,8.5,0,9,8.5,0,10,9.5,0,8,8.5,
 0,8.5,9,0,9,9,0,10,8,0,8.5,9.5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def associations(dataset, nominal_columns=None, mark_columns=False, theil_u=False, plot=True,
return_results = False, **kwargs):
"""
Calculate the correlation/strength-of-association of features in data-set with both categorical (eda_tools) and
continuous features using:
- Pearson's R for continuous-continuous cases
- Correlation Ratio for categorical-continuous cases
- Cramer's V or Theil's U for categorical-categorical cases

:param dataset: NumPy ndarray / Pandas DataFrame
The data-set for which the features' correlation is computed
:param nominal_columns: string / list / NumPy ndarray
Names of columns of the data-set which hold categorical values. Can also be the string 'all' to state that all
columns are categorical, or None (default) to state none are categorical
:param mark_columns: Boolean (default: False)
if True, output's columns' names will have a suffix of '(nom)' or '(con)' based on there type (eda_tools or
continuous), as provided by nominal_columns
:param theil_u: Boolean (default: False)
In the case of categorical-categorical feaures, use Theil's U instead of Cramer's V
:param plot: Boolean (default: True)
If True, plot a heat-map of the correlation matrix
:param return_results: Boolean (default: False)
If True, the function will return a Pandas DataFrame of the computed associations
:param kwargs:
Arguments to be passed to used function and methods
:return: Pandas DataFrame
A DataFrame of the correlation/strength-of-association between all features
"""

dataset = convert(dataset, 'dataframe')
columns = dataset.columns
if nominal_columns is None:
nominal_columns = list()
elif nominal_columns == 'all':
nominal_columns = columns
corr = pd.DataFrame(index=columns, columns=columns)
for i in range(0,len(columns)):
for j in range(i,len(columns)):
if i == j:
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = 1.0
else:
if columns[i] in nominal_columns:
if columns[j] in nominal_columns:
if theil_u:
corr[columns[j]][columns[i]] = theils_u(dataset[columns[i]],dataset[columns[j]])
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = theils_u(dataset[columns[j]],dataset[columns[i]])
else:
cell = cramers_v(dataset[columns[i]],dataset[columns[j]])
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = cell
corr[columns[j]][columns[i]] = cell
else:
cell = correlation_ratio(dataset[columns[i]], dataset[columns[j]])
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = cell
corr[columns[j]][columns[i]] = cell
else:
if columns[j] in nominal_columns:
cell = correlation_ratio(dataset[columns[j]], dataset[columns[i]])
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = cell
corr[columns[j]][columns[i]] = cell
else:
cell, _ = ss.pearsonr(dataset[columns[i]], dataset[columns[j]])
corr[columns[i]][columns[j]] = cell
corr[columns[j]][columns[i]] = cell
corr.fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
if mark_columns:
marked_columns = ['{} (nom)'.format(col) if col in nominal_columns else '{} (con)'.format(col) for col in columns]
corr.columns = marked_columns
corr.index = marked_columns
if plot:
plt.figure(figsize=kwargs.get('figsize',None))
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=kwargs.get('annot',True), fmt=kwargs.get('fmt','.2f'))
plt.show()
if return_results:
return corr

nominal.associations(df, nominal_columns=['Month','Day'])
```

but I just need it to be like this:
[image]

In fact, month and day are nominal features while working hours and temperature are numeric ones. The correlation between numeric and nominal features are computed using Eta, so I want to plot it separately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need filter `DataFrame` by subset of list of columns name:

So change:

```
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=kwargs.get('annot',True), fmt=kwargs.get('fmt','.2f'))
```

to:

```
c1 = ['WorkingHours','Temperature']
c2 = ['Day','Month']
sns.heatmap(corr.loc[c1, c2], annot=kwargs.get('annot',True), fmt=kwargs.get('fmt','.2f'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I already computed the correlation. For numeric vs numeric, I used `Pearson's coefficient` using `.corr()` function. For, numeric vs nominal, I used `Eta`. Finally, for nominal vs. nominal, I used `Cramer's V`. Therefore, I don't need to compute correlation again.

Comment: @ebrahimi - It is only sample, the most important is `df[['WorkingHours','Temperature']]` for filtering by columns names. Be free use it for your real code. ;)

Comment: @ebrahimi - and if still problem with your real code, please add it to question.

Comment: d@ebrahimi - So `nominal.associations` create `DataFrame` for plot or also ploting?

Comment: Thanks. My code (`nominal`) is too long but it computes the correlation as I told. Then, it plots the heatmap which I provided. I could plot a heatmap based on Cramer's V for numeric vs. numeric. The same could be done about numeric vs. numeric. Therefore, I need a separate plot for numeric vs. nominal features.

Comment: sorry, it plots it too.

Comment: @ebrahimi - I am a bit lost. So need modify your `nominal.associations` for ploting only `'WorkingHours','Temperature'` columns? Is not possible use `df[['WorkingHours','Temperature']]` for plot? Or something missing?

Comment: So sorry, I added the `association` function but it is not well-written.

Comment: @ebrahimi - No problem.

Comment: I am not sure if I could do this: `assoc = nominal.associations(df, nominal_columns=['Month','Day'], plot=False, return_results=True)`
`sns.heatmap(assoc.loc[['Day','Month'],['Temperature','WorkingHours']], annot=True, fmt='.2f')` or the colors would not be set correctly if I do this.

Comment: @ebrahimi I understand now, your code filtering necessary columns and index values, but not sure if possible keep original colors, because it is ploting of new DataFrame.